# What database is good for unstructured data

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a project with a great deal of unstructured data. Is there database software or a tool that is suitable for unstructured data. If there are no tools or other software what database design would I use if mysql or sql server are my only choice?

Comment: What type of unstructured data are we talking about?  Text?  Images?  Video?  All of the above?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have enough structured data to formulate a key I'd stick with any DB that supports blobs.

If you're not going to have a structured key I'd go with something like couchDB. It allows you to use unstructured keys to store unstructured data.

If you have unstructured keys and you're absolutely stuck with mysql / sql server you can still accomplish your goal using unstructured data (mysql for instance supports column prefix indexing where you provide it the length of a variable length field to use for indexing ).

Answer (score 1):

[VelocityDB](http://www.velocitydb.com/) is high performance database suitable to handle unstructured data. It is common to create inverted indexes when handling unstructured data. The VelocityDB website and download provides sample code for creating inverted indexes from books, web pages and the entire Wikipedia text.